# Disable text message vibration when on a call

Tags: ios

When I'm on a phone call using my iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3.3, I get the vibration of iMessages in my ear while I'm on the phone. It's irritating to say the least (pun intended.) The recipient can also hear the buzz.

Is there a way to automatically disable all vibrations when on a call? Would the slider on the left-hand side of the phone near the top work? (I'm afraid to try in case it makes it worse.)

Comment: @NimeshNeema while that is a duplicate, it was posted five years ago so I'm not sure if there has been any new features which have been added

Comment: I face the exact same problem and have not been able to find any solution.